# Simple multi-user application

Tags: multi-user

I have been searching a lot for info and examples of the principles of making a simple multi-user web application.

The app i am going to make is used for deadline management and can be described as a simple calendar where users can register events.

I have no problem making this for a single user in PHP or ASP.NET, but how can i make this for multiple users, so they can register and only see their own data.

The app itself is pretty simple, and there will not be many users max. 50-100.

I find it hard to find info about this topic.
My own idea, which probably isn't the right way to do it is:

- When a user creates an event, store it in a table with the user's ID.
- When selecting data, use the logged in user's ID and get the corresponding event(s).

Comment: you need  a host, a server, webservices and probably a database

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend working within a framework in order to avoid re-inventing the wheel.  If you know python, consider [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  If you would prefer to continue working in PHP (you should avoid working with ASP.NET if you are ever going to work with non-Windows developers) try [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).  Ruby on RAILs has some options, as well, but I've never used it.

The way you are attempting to implement this is likely to lead to an oversized, overcomplicated database that is very hard for new developers to get used to.  If you *must* implement this yourself, you should have a user/password table, an events table, and a table linking together the two (e.g assigning ownership).